# How do I prevent the page from scrolling when I zoom on a Google Map in Chrome?

Tags: google-maps, scroll, trackpad, magic-mouse

I am using a Mac Trackpad on a Google Map.
If I two-finger swipe down or up, the map zooms in or out (like it should), but then the entire page scrolls up or down.

I think it has to do with the Trackpad momentum (probably the same on a Magic Mouse).

When I use a normal mouse with a scroll wheel, I don't have the same problem.

I have tried doing things like `e.preventDefault()` in the `scroll` listener of the map element, but no luck.

To see an example, just zoom in or out really fast on Google's own demo page: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple

How do I prevent the entire page from scrolling when I am only trying to zoom the map?

Thank you!

Comment: check this out, maybe it suits http://jsfiddle.net/XNwbt/551/

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery try this:

```
 $("#idOfMap").on("wheel mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
 });
```

When using jQuery prior 1.7 use `bind()` instead of `on()`.

Answer (score 0):

Worked fine for me, try downloading MagicPrefs for your trackpad, it gives you much greater preferences regarding the way your trackpad works.
http://magicprefs.com/

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to accomplish it without having the user change default settings.